# kivy windows package spec with kv file and back ground image

Tags: python, windows, package, kivy

I converted the kivy application to stand alone application by referring the official documentation and some external source.

This is my spec file

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['..\\WordCalc\\main.py'],
             pathex=['E:\\projects\\kivy\\calc\\app'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz, Tree('..\\WordCalc\\'),
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
          name='WordCalc',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False, icon='..\\WordCalc\\icon.ico')
```

In my kivy application I used background image and kv file, how I want to define those external files in the spec files, Please suggest me if anything I missed out or need to improve, Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a specific issue, or are you looking for a code review instead?

Comment: I have an app that has .kv file and images , when i converted to exe using pyinstaller the .kv file and images are not loaded, I have to know ,in the spec file where i need to specify the .kv file and image file and how?

Answer (score 1):

Open the folder in dist and check if you have the images available. If the images are present, your path to them is bad(absolute maybe?).

If they are not present, your `Tree` might be a problem, but not necessarily. If you use images from outside of `main.py` folder, you need to add them to the spec explicitly, but the better solution would be to place them in `main.py` folder.